# Retriving two PFUsers at random from database to user, then not show them again

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have found this [post](https://parse.com/questions/is-it-possible-to-query-for-a-random-object) querying random PFObjects in the Parse forums to be quite helpful, but am having trouble implementing it as query for random PFUsers in my database. As a concrete example, suppose there are 10 users in the database, how would I be able to pull two users at random, and after showing to `current_user` in my app (by "showing" I mean that it will display some attributes of the two users, such as their hometowns), make sure they are not shown again?

My current thoughts are to add an array property to each `PFUser` called `seen_by_current_user`, of which contains a list of user `id`s which are those seen by the `current_user`, and when querying for random users using `PFQuery`, it would only query those `!seen_by` the `current_user`.  Where I am having difficulty is understanding whether this is doable thorough `PFQuery`, and if so how I could implement it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PFQuery whereKey:notContainedIn:](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKey%3anotContainedIn%3a) method is what you would want to use, the second parameter would be the array of user ids the current user has already seen.

Comment: Thank you, this is spot on.  I thought I had dug through all of the PFQueries docs but I suppose I missed this - this was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks again!